# How to randomize fadeTo?

Tags: jquery, random, fadeto

This is a tiny js file, grabbed from somewhere, used in wordpress to make thumbnails fade in on page load.

```
(function($) {
    $('.featured-thumbnail').each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay((i++) * 380).fadeTo(1000, 1); })
})(jQuery);
```

I'd like to add randomness to i.

The questions are: 
Where to use Math.random? 
Should I use Math.floor also? 
Do I need total i? Doesn't appear to be necessary.

Slow learning jQuery newbie.

Comment: What do you want randomise? The opacity, the duration, the delay..?

Comment: Im guessing but if you want to add some randomness to it, you can use Math.floor( (i++) + (Math.random() * 380))

Comment: Sorry, the order at which they fire off. So, that's the delay I think.

Comment: Yes, so this works but the fades all begin at the same time. I did want their beginning points to iterate (if I'm using the term correctly). And sorry for the non-formatting.

$(this).delay(Math.floor(i++) + Math.random() * 380).fadeTo(1000, 1); })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want the thumbnails fading-in in a random order. If you're OK with those fade-ins overlapping, you can say:

```
(function($) {
    var len = $('.featured-thumbnail').length;

    $('.featured-thumbnail').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(Math.floor( Math.random() * 380 * len)).fadeTo(1000, 1); })
})(jQuery);
```

otherwise, you can pick off random elements off your list and fade them in on the same schedule as the original:

```
(function($) {
  // jQuery selectors return array-LIKE objects,
  // but not actual arrays. We need a real array.
  //
  var items = $.makeArray( $('.featured-thumbnail') );
  var i = 0;

  while (items.length > 0)
  {
    // pick a random index within our array
    //
    var idx = Math.floor( Math.random() * items.length );

    // grab that item, remove it from the array.
    // splice() returns an array, so grab the first (only)
    // element from that array. splice() removes the
    // selected element(s) from the original array
    //
    var selected = items.splice(idx, 1)[0]; 

    // delay and fade in as before
    //
    $(selected).delay(i++ * 380).fadeTo(1000, 1);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the order. I'll try them both out this afternoon and letcha know.

Comment: I fixed some typos in the second version - be sure to use the edited code.

Comment: Why do you use `$.makeArray()` instead of `.get()`?

Comment: If you're doing to fade them all at once, why bother selecting a random image?  Why not just iterate through the array and select a random time for each image?

Comment: The first version fades them all in at once. The second does not, and that's the only one selecting random images. As for `makeArray()` vs. `get()`, that's just the approach that sprang to mind. `get()` would certainly work as well.

Comment: Although it's not very mobile friendly for me. Delays are inconsistent on my site (urbaninteractive.us). On the other hand, the example at codepen.io runs fine for me. hmmm